# Error probability of Type I and II

Tags: probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_1, \ldots , X_{10}$ be independent and $N(\mu, 4)$-distributed.

We consider the Gauss-test with $H_0: \mu \geq 2$ and $H_1:\mu<2$, with the significance level $\alpha=5\%$.

1. Determine the distribution of the test statistic for $\mu=1$ and $\mu=3$.
2. Determine the error probability of type II if $\mu=1$.
3. Determine the error probability of type I if $\mu=3$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

1. The test statistic is $$z=\frac{\overline{X}-\mu_0}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}=\frac{\overline{X}-\mu_0}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}}$$ for $\mu_0=1$ or $\mu_0=3$, or not?

   How is this distributed?
2. The error probability of Type II is equal to the probability that we reject the null hypothesis although it is true. But how could we calculate it?
3. The error probability of Type I is equal to the probability that we accept the null hypothesis although it is wrong. But how could we calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The distribution of $\overline X$ is $N(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n})$. Can you clarify if we have $\sigma=4$ or $\sigma^2=4$?

(2) That is not correct. The type II error $\beta$ is the probability that we keep the null hypothesis even though it is incorrect.

$$\beta = P\left(\frac{\overline X-\mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt n} > z^* \mid \mu=1\right)
=P\left(\frac{\overline X-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n} > \frac{\mu_0 -\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n} + z^* \mid \mu=1\right)
=P\left(Z > \frac{2 - 1}{2/\sqrt{10}} - 1.645\right)
$$

(3) I'm afraid that is not correct either. The Type I error is simply $\alpha$, which is the probability that we reject the null hypothesis even though it is correct.

Comment: (1) It is $\sigma^2$. Since $X_i\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ it follows that $\overline{X}\sim N\left (\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right )$, right? Is this therefore also the distribution of $z$ ?

Comment: Yep. And apparently we have $n=10$.

Comment: Ah yes. So we have that $z\sim N(\mu_0, 0.4)$ for $\mu_0=1$ and $\mu_0=3$, right? $$$$ Could you give me a hint how we could calculate the probabilities at (2) and (3) ?

Comment: For (2) we want $\beta = P(\frac{\overline X-\mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt n} > z^* \mid \mu=1)$.

For (3) the answer is $\alpha$.

Comment: So, we have that $$\beta=1-P\left (\frac{\overline{X}-1}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\leq z^{\star}\right )=1-P\left (\frac{\overline{X}-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}}\leq z^{\star}\right )=1-P\left (\frac{\sqrt{10}(\overline{X}-1)}{2}\leq z^{\star}\right ) \\ =1-F\left (\frac{\sqrt{10}(z^{\star}-1)}{2}\right )$$ Right? Is $z^{\star}$ equal to $2$ ?

Comment: With a one-tailed test of $\alpha=5\%$, we have $z^*=1.645$.
Oh, and $\mu_0=2$ isn't it?

Comment: Oh yes! So we have the following: $$\beta=1-\Phi \left (\frac{\sqrt{10}(1.645-2)}{2}\right )=1-\Phi \left (\frac{\sqrt{10}(-0.355)}{2}\right )=1-\Phi \left (-0.561304\right )=\Phi \left (0.561304\right )=0.712705$$ right?

Comment: We have that $\mu_0=2$, but we also have that the distribution of $\overline X$ is $N(1,\sigma^2/n)$...

Comment: Ok, but what does that mean? Which expected value do we have to use?

Comment: The expected value is $\mu=1$.

Comment: Ok. Do we have then the following? $$\beta=1-P\left (\frac{\overline{X}-\mu_0}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\leq z^{\star}\right )=1-P\left (\frac{\overline{X}-2}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}}\leq z^{\star}\right ) =1-\Phi\left (\frac{z^{\star}-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}}\right )$$  Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Not quite. I've added the formula to the answer.

Comment: Ahh ok! So, we have the following: \begin{align*}\beta&=P\left(\frac{\overline X-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}} > \frac{\mu_0 -\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}} +1.645 \mid \mu=1\right)  =P\left(Z > \frac{2 - 1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}} + 1.645\right)  \\ & =P\left(Z > \frac{\sqrt{10}}{2} + 1.645\right)  \approx P\left(Z > 3.22614\right)  = 1-P\left(Z \leq 3.22614\right) \\ & =1-\Phi \left (\frac{3.22614-\mu}{\sigma}\right )  = 1-\Phi \left (\frac{3.22614-1}{2}\right )  = 1-\Phi \left (1.11307\right ) \\ & = 1-0.867161  = 0.132839 \end{align*} right?

Comment: I've just realized that it should be $- 1.645$ instead of $+ 1.645$. Btw, $Z$ has $\mu=0$ and $\sigma =1$, so we shouldn't subtract 1 again, nor divide by 2 again.

Comment: Why is it negativ? Does it hold that $z^*=\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)$ ?

Comment: It's negative because we reject $H_0$ iff $\frac{\overline X - \mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt n} < -1.645$. That is, we have a left-tailed area of rejection.  Depending on the test, $z^*$ can be $\Phi^{-1}(\alpha)$, $\Phi^{-1}(1- \alpha)$, $\Phi^{-1}(\frac\alpha 2)$, or $\Phi^{-1}(1-\frac\alpha 2)$. In this case we have $z^*=\Phi{-1}(\alpha)$.

Comment: So, if we have a left-tailed area, we reject $H_0$ if $Z<\Phi (\alpha)=-1.65$, right? So, we have that \begin{align*}\beta&=P\left(\frac{\overline X-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}} > \frac{\mu_0 -\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}} -1.645 \mid \mu=1\right)\approx P\left(Z > -0.0638612\right) \\ & = 1-P\left(Z \leq -0.0638612\right)=1-\Phi \left (-0.0638612\right ) =\Phi \left (0.0638612\right )=0.52546\end{align*}

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Thank you so much!! :-)